# Is there a way to export the SSL certificate (.pem and .key) from your instance for use in Postman?

Tags: ssl-certificate, servicenow

Our SIT instance makes outbound calls that are MASSL enabled. If I were to make those same calls via postman, would it be possible to export the certificates from the instance (since they are already there and are allowing successful calls to the target endpoints)?

I combed through the x.509 Certificates table but there are so many of them, so unsure which one to check and how to export them.

[image]